# PostgreSQL query to split based on Strings & Concatenate them into new individual columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I have a table Rulebook with a column "Rules" like this:

[image]

I want a output like this:

[image]

I want a postgreSQL query that will split each rule based on the '|' & put them into new columns as Rule 1 to 'n'. Trying out couple of case statements, need your help to achieve the output. Interested to know the MSSQL Server query too. Thanks!

Comment: Please post formatted text instead of images to make it easier for people to duplicate your issue. Images aren't formatted properly anyway. Also post any attempts you have made at the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`string_to_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) to split the string into multiple elements that can be accessed individually:

```
select rules[1] as rule_1, 
       rules[2] as rule_2,
       rules[3] as rule_3,
       rules[4] as rule_4,
       rules[5] as rule_5,
       rules[6] as rule_6
from (
  select string_to_array(rules, '|') as rules
  from rulebook
) t
```